# ldap query get all users in a group node.js

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap

failing to find any info on the matter.
I need to query an active directory server with a specified group name, and to receive back all the users it contains.

Then i can iterate through those users and use their first&last name + email + phone + accountname.

Is all that possible using Node.js?
Can someone liberate me from this headache?

Comment: We are not here to write code for you. We are here to help you while you write the code yourself.

Comment: I wasn't asking for any code written for me. I was asking for a link or a library name so i could research and do so myself.
I did find such a lib and it provides the solution i was looking for.

Comment: Library recommendation are also off-topic for this website. That's actually in the FAQ, see point 4 ("Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool…") over http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It wasn't a 'recommendation' that i asked for, i asked for a library example so i will know:
1. It's possible with node.js.
2. Learn how to do it.

I also stated that in the question note: "is all that possible using node.js" since i'm not a pro at it.

Anyhow, now that the question was answered, i appreciate the time you took to not help me at all and wish you a good day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory#getUsersForGroup

```
var groupName = 'Employees';

var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
ad.getUsersForGroup(groupName, function(err, users) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }

  if (! users) console.log('Group: ' + groupName + ' not found.');
  else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(users));
  }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm after all these years :)

Answer (score 0):

The other solution posted is for ActiveDirectory, as a more general answer, you need a query which will return the "member" attribute from a group.
I was able to accomplish this using [ldapjs](https://github.com/ldapjs/node-ldapjs)

```js
import ldap from 'ldapjs'

const client = ldap.createClient({ url: ['ldap://localhost:389'] })
client.on('error', (err) => { console.log(err) } )
client.bind("cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com", "password", (err) => {console.log(err)})

function logCallback(err,res) {
    if(!res) {
        console.log(err)
        return
    }
    
    res.on('searchRequest', (searchRequest) => {
        console.log('searchRequest: ', searchRequest.messageID);
    });
    res.on('searchEntry', (entry) => {
        console.log('entry: ' + JSON.stringify(entry.object));
    });
    res.on('searchReference', (referral) => {
        console.log('referral: ' + referral.uris.join());
    });
    res.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('error: ' + err.message);
    });
    res.on('end', (result) => {
        console.log('status: ' + result?.status);
    });
}

client.search("dc=example,dc=com",{filter:"(&(objectclass=groupofnames)(cn=users))",scope:"sub"},logCallback)
```

```
> searchRequest:  8
entry: {"dn":"cn=users,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com","controls":[],"cn":"users","description":"All Users","member":["uid=user,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com","uid=user1,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com","uid=user2,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com"],"objectClass":["groupOfNames","top"]}
status: 0
```

The return value has a field "member" with a list of all users in the group.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.getUserLists = (req, res) => {
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');

var ad = new ActiveDirectory({
    url: 'domainName.com',
    baseDN: 'dc=domain,dc=com',
});

var opts = {
    includeMembership: ['user'], // can use 'all','group','user'
    baseDN: 'cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=domain,dc=com',
    includeDeleted: false
};

ad.find(opts, function (err, results) {
    if ((err) || (!results)) {
        res.send('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }
    res.send(JSON.stringify(results))
});
```